# Timestamp of a Document in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I would like to know the current timestamp of a document
I also need how to find the timestamp of same document when it is updated

is it possible?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve, can you be a bit more descriptive, please?

Comment: I need to try incremental update 
so i need time stamps of older and latest one so i need time stamp of document when it is updated lastly
so i can compare time to present to lastest updated timestamp

Comment: OK, that still sounds like a solution for a particular problem. Why do you have to do that?

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked here, sounds like what you need: https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-timestamp

```
xdmp:document-timestamp(
   $uri as xs:string
) as xs:integer?
```

**Summary**

Returns timestamp of the most recent visible update to a document, lock, or property. Returns the empty sequence if no document, lock, or property exists.

$uri is the URI of the document, lock, or property.

Example:

```
xdmp:document-timestamp("example.xml")
=> 13384772182196660
```

Comment: Hi @Saša 
Thanks for replying
i am getting some thing like this
com.marklogic.client.impl.ServerEvaluationCallImpl@2acf57e3
where i am not able to see the actual output

Comment: It works for me in the MarkLogic QC. It seems that you're trying to call this from Java. Are you getting an exception?